# Capacitor Placements

Tags: capacitor, circuit-analysis, filter

I have been studying the effects of using capacitors in different locations and one I have come across is split caps across a signal output. I've re-created the design in LTSPICE and screen-cap'd it:

[image]

Let's assume for the sake of argument that the Signal In and Signal Out are already balanced to be half of Vcc, (24V_Ref in the screencap). Is there anything gained by using the above capacitor layout compared to the following simple RC filter? My gut tells me that if the signal is already balanced to half Vcc, then it IS useful, but playing with it in LTSPICE doesn't show any difference between these two layouts.

[image]

Comment: Where did you see that circuit?  Usually you wouldn't do that, since you're now introducing power supply noise into your signal.

Comment: You never told us what the objective of the circuit is. We cannot say what you have to gain if we do not know what you are trying to do.

Comment: In my system there exists a signal input that is AC in nature with a DC offset such that the signal is purposefully balanced to half Vcc. In my case, the objective of the circuit to act as a simple RC filter, but are there other cases where this might be a valuable layout to keep in mind?

It's not a common thing, but I've seen it in older design theory manuals (that didn't explain why). I'll make the assumption that my power supply rail is as stable as my ground plane. (Obviously, in the case of one being noisier then it would be better to connect capacitors to the more stable option)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since in small signal analysis all DC sources are shorted, both circuits would result in the same small signal equivalent circuit. Connecting both capacitors to Vcc would also be equivalent. So for the signal it doesn't matter if the capacitances are connected to GND or the supply voltage.

It also doesn't really matter if the signal is balanced to half Vcc or not. There is no DC biasing done in those circuits. You might imply that there is some sort of voltage divider created by the capacitors which is not the case for DC.

Comment: Why doesn't the capacitor pair create a voltage divider when split between rails?

Comment: Ah! That was a dumb question. There is no path for current to flow, so of course it doesn't act as a voltage divider. Thank you for your time and input!

Comment: Yes, so whatever your DC offset of your input signal is, it will also be present at your output signal.

Comment: The capacitors DO act as a voltage divider. But only for AC signals. If you have a noisy or ripply power supply, it will couple half of the noise/ripple to the line. Or when the power supply rises and falls during powerup and powerdown. If you use a switch to connect the supply so that it jumps from 0V to 24V immediately, the filtered line would also immediately jump to 12V.

Comment: Good point. I was referring to voltage division at DC, but not really explicitly saying so.

Comment: Capacitors have different behaviors between AC and DC. In DC a capacitor after being charged becomes almost an open circuit ( almost is due to leakage current) but in AC it becomes a frequency dependent resistor(there are other differences as well e.g phase shift and no heat is created).